# Replacing VBA filter array with custom array

Tags: arrays, vba, filtering

I have an array that has some cells that invalidates ranges of the array. I've stored the data to filter the affected rows out, but when the array is replaced in the filter it either filters everything or nothing.

```
 For i = LBound(SOS_array1) To UBound(SOS_array1)
    filter1(i) = CStr(SOS_array1(i, 1))
Next i

Sheets("NSR " & NSR1).Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$A:$T$T").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array(Join(filter1, ",")), _
                                            Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Where Sos_array1 is the data to be filtered as integers and filter1 is the data converted to string.

Comment: What happens when you try `Criteria1:=Join(filter1, ",")` without the `Array(`?

Comment: Correct is `Criteria1:=filter1` because filter1 is itself an array - see examples at [Range.AutoFilter method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)

Comment: Running 'Criteria1:=filter1' does not apply any filter to the sheet. @АлексейР

Comment: Running Criteria1:=Join(filter1, ",") also does not apply any filter to the sheet. @Toddleson

Comment: @Acbischoff it's because the Range("$A$A:$T$T") has incorrect address.

Comment: @АлексейР That fixed the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Sheets("NSR " & NSR1).Range("A:T").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=filter1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

or, better:

```
Sheets("NSR " & NSR1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=filter1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```